# Safari issue with justify-content: flex-end; align-items: flex-end;

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I am designing a messenger layout and I am struggling to fix few things on Safari as it seems a compatibility issues.

http://animgram.com/fb/index.html If you open this link on Google Chrome and Safari. Google Chrome is the correct view but on Safari it is not showing correctly.

I am struggling to set this class.

```
.self {
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Please Note: only Safari is the problem. IE, Chrome and Firefox are perfectly OK.

Comment: Please be aware of proper tagging.  This has nothing to do with the Adobe/Apache UI Framework so I removed the Flex tag.  I suspect it relates to FlexBox the CSS framework; so I added the Flexbox tag.  If that is incorrect, you can correct the tagging.

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: Latest Version for Windows 5.1.7

Answer (score 17):

Safari < 7.0 only has an implementation of the old 2009 Flexbox specification, which is very different from the modern specification:

```
.foo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: start; /* justify-content */
    -webkit-box-align: start; /* align-items */
}
```

This might be helpful:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Answer (score 0):

Use `-ms-flex-align: end !important;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).